# Marionette Modules missing after minifying the files through grunt

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, marionette

I'm using Backbonejs with RequirejS to create an application and used
Grunt as a build tool. Minified files were generated using grunt task "grunt-requirejs".

After that I implemented MarionetteJs for using the marionette modules and after implementing marionette modules in the application, the problem started occurring in Grunt build process. When i'm running the application with minified file, i'm getting error

```
"uncaught Error: undefined missing modules/main/mainApp"
```

mainApp.js is my main module which would govern the other modules.

Code snippet
app.js -

```
define([ 'marionette' ], function(Marionette) {
    var MainApplication = new Marionette.Application();

   MainApplication.on("start", function(){
    if(Backbone.history){
      require(['modules/main/mainApp'], function (MainApp) {

          Backbone.history.start();

          MainApp.start();
      });
    }
  });
return MainApplication;
}
```

I googled a lot about this question but couldn't find a concrete solution.

Do i have to include any other task for minifying the marionette files?

Also i came up with this [blogpost](http://derickbailey.com/2014/06/10/browserify-my-new-choice-for-modules-in-a-browser-backbone-app/) , which confuses whether to used Requirejs with Marionette modules.

Any suggestions/approach for checking the marionette files are minified and are working correctly would be really helpful.

**Edit:**
Added code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. It was just simply adding one more option to the optimization task.

In my grunt task

```
requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    findNestedDependencies: true,
                    // Edited for brevity
                }
            }
        },
```

I added `findeNestedDependencies : true` and it actually picked up the nested dependencies.
I got the reference from David Sulc's book for RequireJS, BackboneJS and Marionette. In this   book he was optimizing the application with RequireJS optimizer and then i found that attribute in the build.js file.